# How to group results per month since there is operator for month?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

When I query and step using make-series I can choose to step by hour (1h) day (1d) but how do I handle when I want the step to be per month? (1m) seems to be per minute

My query looks like this

```
let _timePeriodInHours = abs(datetime_diff('hour', _startTime, _endTime));
let _stepConfig = case(_timePeriodInHours <= 24, timespan(1h), _timePeriodInHours <= 744, timespan(1d), timespan(30d));
tilldevicedata
| where todatetime(TransactionTimeStampUtc) between (_startTime.._endTime)
| where Brand has_any (_brand)
| where Country == _country
| where Store has_any (_store)
| make-series TotalDiscounts = sum(TransactionValueDiscount), TotalSales = sum(TransactionValueNet) default = 0 on todatetime(TransactionTimeStampUtc) step _stepConfig
```

The idea is to have the graph per month if user selects more than 31 days apart in the dateTime Selector but it seems not easily possible, it works fine for hour and day but as soon as I pass 744 hours in the _timePeriodInHours  variable the stepCOnfig becomes 30d whcih is not really correct for month and it also looks weird ause it ends up with the graph showing a Time instead of a month

How can I handle the grouping per month when user selects over 744h and stepConfig should be 1M = 1 month?

----- EDIT -----

Almost there

**LAST 24 HOURS**

This works fine given the solution below, see how the hours are looking normal as in 18:00 19:00 etc

[image: Last 24 h]

**LAST 14 Days**
Using Last 14 days this also looks good note the month etc is nicely spread

[image: last 14d]

Now here comes the weird parts, if I select last 12 hours, notice how the time is not shown nicely any longer as 18:00 it adds milliseconds etc and looks totally weird

**LAST 12h**
[image: last 12h]

And the weirdest of them all is last 60 days which looks totally absurd with just a weird timestamp ?

**LAST 60d**
[image]

Currently query looks like this

```
let _timePeriod = _endTime - _startTime;
let _stepConfig = case(_timePeriod <= 24h, 1h, 1d);
tilldevicedata
| extend dttm = todatetime(TransactionTimeStampUtc)
| where dttm between (_startTime.._endTime)
| where Brand has_any (_brand)
| where Country == _country
| where Store has_any (_store)
| make-series TotalDiscounts = sum(TransactionValueDiscount) default = 0, TotalSales = sum(TransactionValueNet) default = 0 on dttm = case(_timePeriod <= 744h, dttm, startofmonth(dttm)) step _stepConfig
| mv-apply TotalDiscounts, TotalSales, dttm to typeof(datetime) on (where _timePeriod <= 744h or dttm == startofmonth(dttm) 
| summarize make_list(TotalSales), make_list(dttm))
| render timechart
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "month" timespan, so some tricks are required here.
While this can be solved pretty easily by using `summarize` instead of `make-series`, by doing that we lose a main advantage of `make-series`, which is the gap filling of missing data.
Therefore, here is a solution based on `make-series`.

The main trick here is to use `make-series` with `1d` step for the monthly report, **for a data that was already grouped by month** (this is achieved by using `make-series ... on ... startofmonth(dttm)...`), and after that keeping the data only for the 1st of every month.

```
// Generation of a data sample. Not part of the solution.
let tilldevicedata = materialize(range i from 1 to 1000000 step 1 | extend dttm = ago(365d*rand()) | where dttm !between (ago(5h) .. 3h) and dttm !between (ago(7d) .. 3d));
// The solution starts here.
let _startTime = ago(600d);
let _endTime = now();
let _timePeriod = _endTime - _startTime;
let _stepConfig = case(_timePeriod <= 24h, 1h, 1d);
tilldevicedata
| make-series count() on dttm = case(_timePeriod <= 744h, dttm, startofmonth(dttm)) from bin(_startTime, _stepConfig) to _endTime step _stepConfig
| mv-apply count_, dttm to typeof(datetime) on (where _timePeriod <= 744h or dttm == startofmonth(dttm) | summarize make_list(count_), make_list(dttm))
| render timechart
```

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22STW/CMAyG70j8B++WTqWF8XVgnHbYbdqBOwrEpdHapEoMjIkfPyftWJGoVFWyX9vPazfP4R0NOknaGrAFSFCSJHhZNxVm8GEJGukopKhE8LY6Bmk2HFRIQLqqFJ70HmPVGmpJ6LSs9A8KJ80BQUPhbA0TIAuTcXzAEzYcuQJ+ExoFiqjmYnmwYrqYq2euVCJJWHAu0WGbf9ohnRENiKCblwlkGUz5I/863CuWqlWoJFkNB3kOmx4/I7ArD6F952UbQxtdY4eyGI9VKI1JxuxSxp7FLUwc+2THVnHmJhr1mq1u3bF5s6bQB1bupUfRL35dw8usTGES3jj1frXDwZV3+4Ujz3r0sLdHQyIBdtIt71HL5Sz0DIK0NWyL2hoqRQjxfuNldtqIf9y0T5qEo91cxav1spHpNJJNU11aoG07LFTRpUFbCGbHwBRJRXvNB5BgXedj/QCU/wN/rGvp+K+KW9hW2pNoRyZpL9T6CmCOqdFBGLUvueEvOlrOp+kCAAA=)

#### Monthly

_startTime = ago(600d)

[image: Monthly]

#### Daily

_startTime = ago(15d)

[image: Daily]

#### Hourly

_startTime = ago(21h)

[image: Hourly]

Comment: OMG lol ok this will take some digesting

Comment: Be careful what you wish for 

Comment: Not sure why I get issues on 2 out of 4 use cases, it works great but sems to break on two instances

Comment: You might not have data for the requested period

Comment: Last 12h you can see I have data but it still only shows one dot and no padded 0's and also the time stamp looks so weird I dont understand and for sure for 60 days I have data since it works for 14days  or am I misunderstanding you? the timestamp on the 60 days looks totally bizarre no? I expected it to say May something or at least something with a month in it ?

Comment: My bad, making a quick fix.

Comment: Done. `from` and `to` should be used in `make-series` to reflect the desired range, or it is determined by the actual data and might cause issues in case of missing data.  Note that the `where` clause for the period filtering is not necessary anymore and was removed. In addition, `start` must be binned to `1d` in order for the monthly report to work and preferably the daily report should be binned also to `1d` while the hourly report should be binned to `1h`

Comment: Done. `from` and `to` should be used in `make-series` to reflect the desired range, or it is determined by the actual data and might cause issues in case of missing data.  Note that the `where` clause for the period filtering is not necessary anymore and was removed. In addition, `start` must be binned to `1d` in order for the monthly report to work and preferably the daily report should be binned also to `1d` while the hourly report should be binned to `1h` for nicer presentation

Comment: If I could upvote 1000 times I would I really don't know how to fully express my gratitude here I really learned a lot and I really appreciate this

Comment: My pleasure :-)

Comment: A small code simplification: `from bin(_startTime, _stepConfig)`